# ¿Como retornar un formato de string con C#?

Tags: c#, string

Tengo el siguiente valor.

```
String dato="SDI87H";
```

Y deseo retornar SD-I8-7H

He probado con

```
 String.Format("{0:##-##-##}", dato);
```

Pero no resulta, ya que el valor que se le debe entregar es numérico, pero en este caso debo entregar un string, para que me añada guiones.

Me gustaría saber el formato o expresión regular de como hacer el retorno en el formato deseado que he planteado en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La funcion format se usa para formatear numeros y fechas en cosas estandares. En tu caso, no hay una funcion para formatear cadenas. Sin embargo, puedes armar vos mismo la cadena concatenando los pedazos.

En tu caso, algo asi devolveria la cadena que estas buscando.

```
String datonuevo = dato.Substring(0,2) + "-" + dato.Substring(2,2) + "-" + dato.Substring(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

O puedes usar esta horrorosa función... (no me juzguen ando aburrido)

```
recursiva("SDI87H", 0, 2, "-");

public StringBuilder sb { set; get; }

public void recursiva(string cadena, int indiceInicialCorte, int tajada, string caracteres)
{
    //sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (sb == null)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    if (indiceInicialCorte + tajada < cadena.Length)
    {
        sb.Append(cadena.Substring(indiceInicialCorte, tajada) + caracteres);
        //micadena += cadena.Substring(indiceInicialCorte, tajada) + caracteres;
        recursiva(cadena, indiceInicialCorte + tajada, tajada, caracteres);
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(cadena.Substring(indiceInicialCorte, tajada - (indiceInicialCorte + tajada - cadena.Length)));
        //micadena += cadena.Substring(indiceInicialCorte, tajada - (indiceInicialCorte + tajada - cadena.Length));
    }

    micadena = sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción usando LINQ, que básicamente divide la cadena de entrada en grupos de 2 caracteres y después les une con un guion `-`:

```
var datoformat = String.Join("-",Enumerable.Range(0, dato.Length / 2)
                             .Select(x => dato.Substring(x*2, 2)).ToArray()
                            );
```

Para usar esta solución hay que tener en cuenta que la cadena de entrada sea multiplo de 2, si no descartará el último caracter